# Does Qt application need OpenGL / Directx without specifically using any OpenGL-based widgets?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

We have a Qt based (C++) application, which even when run with no direct opengl/graphics widgets being created, still seems to load QtOpenGL4.dll and other libraries (e.g. d3dcompiler). We were thinking ideally it shouldn't have used them but it does, and thus they need to be present when we deploy the application. Does Qt GUI intrinsically need OpenGL or OpenGL ES (with ANGLE) with most of its widgets (even list/tree/text etc.)? If not most, are there any specific seemingly simple widgets that use them?

Comment: If you are not using any of `***GLWidget` and not using QtQuick/QML - then no. Anyway, QtQuick may be configured to use software rendering (with some restrictions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is depending on how Qt libraries are built. When using prebuild binaries (for windows) opengl support is enabled and library is loaded dynamically thus there is no explicit linking to system opengl or directx libraries. I could not recall was there some differences between Qt4 and Qt5 how this is implemented.

[This document enlights the mechanism more.](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/windows-requirements.html)

Comment: Thanks! Just a couple more questions to confirm, I just noticed that we're using QPainter class inside our Qt text edit control. Can that use OpenGL/DX? Also, will text anti-aliasing use them internally?

Comment: If the control is delivered from QWidget then software raster is used for painting. Anti-aliasing is just a hint for rendering backend how to paint stuff and it may or may not be supported by the backend.